# Problem in "<execution>" tag trying to add frontend-maven-plugin to java proyect

Tags: java, maven, npm

I´m following a tutorial to implement React+Spring Boot, the problem arises after adding the webpack.config.js file to the project. When i do it, then an error shows up at the pom.xml file, specifically at the < execution > tag, in the  webpack build

I´ve tried putting other frontend-maven-plugin source codes but honestly I don´t know which one to pick. I´m doing it kind of blindly. Once I open the error alert it shows me like 1000 errors so i don´t know where might be the problem.

This is the webpack.config.js:

```js
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main/js/app.js',
    devtool: 'sourcemaps',
    cache: true,
    mode: 'development',
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: './src/main/resources/static/built/bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: path.join(__dirname, '.'),
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
                    }
                }]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

This is the pom:

```js
<!-- tag::frontend-maven-plugin[] -->
   <plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <configuration>
     <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
     <execution>
      <id>install node and npm</id>
      <goals>
       <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
       <nodeVersion>v10.11.0</nodeVersion>
       <npmVersion>6.4.1</npmVersion>
      </configuration>
     </execution>
     <execution>
      <id>npm install</id>
      <goals>
       <goal>npm</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
       <arguments>install</arguments>
      </configuration>
     </execution>
          // bug shows up in the tag <execution> right below:
     <execution>
      <id>webpack build</id>
      <goals>
       <goal>webpack</goal>
      </goals>
     </execution>
    </executions>
   </plugin>
   <!-- end::frontend-maven-plugin[] -->
```

This is the error output:

```js
Failed to run task (com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:webpack:webpack build:generate-resources) org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Failed to run 
 task at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.mojo.AbstractFrontendMojo.execute(AbstractFrontendMojo.java:100) at 
 org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137) at 
 org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:333) at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.lambda$7(MavenImpl.java:1380) at 
 org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177) at 
 org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112) at 
 org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1379) at 
 org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.build(MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.java:52) at 
 org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.build(MavenBuilderImpl.java:137) at 
 org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:173) at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:1) at 
 org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:116) at 
 org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177) at 
 org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112) at 
 org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:106) at 
 org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177) at 
 org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151) at 
 org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99) at 
 org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:87) at 
 org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:201) at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:833) at 
 org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45) at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:220) at 
 org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:263) at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:316) at 
 org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45) at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:319) at 
 org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:371) at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:392) at 
 org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:154) at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:244) at 
 org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63) Caused by: com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.TaskRunnerException: 'webpack.js ' failed. at 
 com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.NodeTaskExecutor.execute(NodeTaskExecutor.java:63) at 
 com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.mojo.WebpackMojo.execute(WebpackMojo.java:64) at 
 com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.mojo.AbstractFrontendMojo.execute(AbstractFrontendMojo.java:94) ... 31 more Caused by: 
 com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.ProcessExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\milja\eclipse-
 workspace\muntrain_complete\target\node\node.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\milja\eclipse-workspace\muntrain_complete"): CreateProcess error=2, El sistema no puede 
 encontrar el archivo especificado at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.ProcessExecutor.execute(ProcessExecutor.java:84) at 
 com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.ProcessExecutor.executeAndRedirectOutput(ProcessExecutor.java:64) at 
 com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.NodeExecutor.executeAndRedirectOutput(NodeExecutor.java:29) at 
 com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.NodeTaskExecutor.execute(NodeTaskExecutor.java:58) ... 33 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:
 \Users\milja\eclipse-workspace\muntrain_complete\target\node\node.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\milja\eclipse-workspace\muntrain_complete"): CreateProcess error=2, El 
 sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source) at 
 org.apache.commons.exec.launcher.Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Java13CommandLauncher.java:61) at 
 org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.launch(DefaultExecutor.java:279) at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:336) at 
 org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166) at 
 com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.ProcessExecutor.execute(ProcessExecutor.java:74) ... 36 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, El sistema 
 no puede encontrar el archivo especificado at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method) at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source) at 
 java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source) ... 43 more
```

Comment: Please add the error output as well to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I had the the same problem and solved it executing the `mvn clean install` commmand on the project's root directory.

I use Linux Ubuntu, and in my case, the *target/* directory of the project was locked, so I had to unlock it executing the command `sudo chown -R user projectRootFoolder`(Replace user with your Ubuntu user and projectRootFoolder with the project name) before executing the *mvn clean install* command.